# Spring Boot - работа header

Tags: java, spring, rest, header, controller

Есть некоторое Spring Boot приложение, в нем реализована возможность загружать в и выгружать из бд файлы, которые в бд и хранятся (файлы маленькие, субд postgresql, формат bytea).
И я ни в какую не могу понять как работает следующий метод контроллера, с помощью которого эти файлы и загружаются:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<FileEntity> optionalFileEntity = fileService.getFile(id);

        if(optionalFileEntity.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        FileEntity fileEntity = optionalFileEntity.get();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileEntity.getFileName() + "\"")
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(fileEntity.getContentType()))
                .body(fileEntity.getData());
    }
```

До последнего **return** все понятно, дальше мрак.
Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает последний **return**, желательно поэтапно - что и зачем это. Каким образом данная конструкция позволяет загружать файлы из бд.
(Настолько сильно не понимаю в какую сторону копать, что даже у гугла не знаю как лучше это спросить, офф документация спринга меньше путаницы не сделала)

Comment: Не очень понятно что именно вам не понятно) Судя по коду метод fileService#getFile по ID достаёт мета-информацию о файле + сам файл в виде массива байтов. После чего из мета-информации и массива байтов формируется ответ сервера, где сам файл передаётся в виде массива байтов в теле ответа, а мета информация передаётся в заголовках. Сам спринг тут почти не при чём.

Comment: Мне именно часть с header/contentType/body и не понятна. Если убрать хоть один из этих методов, файл уже не вернется. Почему именно такой header, почему именно такой contentType и почему именно такой body (видимо он как раз голые байты и возвращает, но до кучи написал, на всякий случай).
Обязательна ли такая структура "заголовок-тип контента-тело" всегда, или это одна из форм... У меня ужасная каша в голове(

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут описано зачем нужен заголовок [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). Если кратко - по этому заголовку клиент (например бразузер) понимает, что в теле ответа - файл. В значении заголовка передаётся надо ли этот файл скачивать через диалог (и какое имя файлу дать) или отобразить прямо в окне браузера (в таком случае значение заголовка должно быть `inline`)

[Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) просто описывает какие данные передаются в теле ответа, чтобы клиент (например браузер) знал как данные отобразить. Например, можно указать что данные - это текст в определённой кодировке: `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Или pdf документ: `application/pdf`. Или картинка: `image/png`

В теле ответа же просто байты, из которых состоит файл.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! То, что мне надо поглубже изучить структуру HTTP-сообщения понятно, но может подскажешь более конкретное направление темы? Либо хороший источник, где можно наиболее комплексно получить информацию? (Гуглом +/- умею пользоваться, про личный опыт больше интересуюсь)

Comment: Если интересует моё личное мнение - то углублять нет смысла. Содержимое ответа я взял просто из гугла по названиям заголовков. До этого я не знал, что первый заголовок так используется. Что не мешало мне последние несколько лет писать код, который позволяет скачивать файлы. Обычно достаточно вгуглить как вернуть файл из контроллера и добиться его работоспособности. Т.е. основная идея - решать вопросы по мере поступления, а не изучать вообще всю теорию, которая не факт, что вся пригодится и неизбежно забудется без подкрепления практикой.